# How to make rows selected for primeng table row expansion?

Tags: html, typescript, primeng

I'm working with primeng table row expansion. I'm working with this example :https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-7gxyuy?file=src/app/app.component.html
I tried to make the expansion rows selected each one  but I failed, I did added this code but not working.

```
 <ng-template pTemplate="rowexpansion" let-rowData let-columns="columns" let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
<tr *ngFor="let subEvent of rowData.subEvents" [pSelectableRow]="subEvent[rowIndex]">
  <td [style.width.px]='40'></td>
  <td [attr.colspan]="columns.length">
    {{subEvent.code}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `rowExpandMode="single"` to `p-table`, the default value is `multiple`

```
 <p-table [columns]="events.headers" [value]="events.data" dataKey="id" #eventTable
              selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedEvent"
              (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)" (onRowUnselect)="cancelUnselect($event)"
              (onRowExpand)="test($event)"
              rowExpandMode="single"
        >
```